# Creating checkboxes based on a value for something else

Tags: database, ms-access, checkbox, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am making a database that is kind of like a to-do list.

In my tasks table, I have a field called 'TaskCompletionDate'. This is an optional field as it will only be filled in once the task is complete.

I am creating a query of all the tasks and details for them, but in the query would I be able to include a checkbox that is checked if a completion date does exist and unchecked if a completion date doesn't exist?

Furthering on this, in my Tasks form could I make a checkbox that again shows whether it is complete or not but if I click it then it automatically updates the completion date based on the current date and deletes the completion date if it is unticked?

Answer (score 0):

For the last point in your question - yes. This could be done using a bound form and a little VBA or a query. You would just add a Checkbox to your form, and in the `OnClick` event, set your field to `Date` in VBA or `Date()` in SQL.

For your main question, add this field to your query:

```
 IIf(IsNull([TaskCompletionDate]),"No","Yes")
```

Right click the field you just added in QBE, and select `Properties`. On the General Tab, select the Format drop down and select "Yes/No". Save the query.

Now you have a field in your query that is a `Yes/No` field, and is populated whether or not the `TaskCompletionDate` is Null or has a value.

To get this on your form:

1. Add a Checkbox control to your form.
2. Right Click the Checkbox
3. Properties -> Control Source: Whatever you named your field that
   checks for `TaskCompletionDate`.
4. Save your form.

When you view your records, the checkbox will be checked or unchecked, accordingly.

Comment: OK so I got the basic of getting the checkbox to tick/untick based on the taskcompletion date field but I still have not been able to get the completion date to update to the current date the checkbox is clicked I have in the on click action =[TaskCompletionDate]=Date(). This is not working though, so I can I tell it in SQL to set the TaskCompletionDate field to the current date?

Comment: It depends on if you're using bound forms or not. There are generally a few different ways to do this, but if the fields are bound to the table, this can be done a little easier.